# Flow over a "finite" flat plate in CFD

Tags: fluent, fluid-dynamics, ansys

I am trying to simulate the turbulent, transient flow of water over a **vertically** oriented flat plate that has **finite length and depth** in ANSYS Fluent. This simulation aims to focus on what is happening within the boundary layer, so after using ANSYS Mesher to make the mesh, I think I should be using the k-epsilon model. Since I think k-epsilon is the way to go, I used this [y+ calculator](https://volupe.se/wall-y-calculator-when-meshing-a-geometry-for-cfd-analysis-this-handy-volupe-calculator-computes-the-height-of-the-first-mesh-cell-off-the-wall-required-to-achieve-a-desired-y-using-flat-plate-boun/) for a y+=30 at x=15 m and Re = 1.98e+9 I was given a first cell height of **1.133e-5 m which I used in the last ratio boundary layer method 15 layers**. I tried running this simulation, slowly ramping up the velocity after some time steps, and changing the time step size to maintain a CFL between 0.7 and 0.9.

Here are my boundary conditions:
[image]

- The flat plate with dimensions L x D on the x/y plane is a normal no-slip wall. (yellow green surface)
- The top and bottom surfaces are L x H parallel to the x/z plane I've set as a wall but with an applied shear stress of zero. (gray surfaces)
- I have a velocity inlet Vx and a pressure outlet at zero gage pressure since I am **not including body forces currently**. (blue and red arrows)
- Finally the far wall is also treated as a wall with an applied shear stress of zero, where H >= 5L.

After running the simulation, ramping up the inlet velocity as I described prior, I was able to achieve residuals for all values between 1e-4 and 1e-12. However, when I looked at my results I was alarmed to see 1) **Cf near 240** (using the area average of the definition in ANSYS) and 2) a y+ contour in the xz plane where **y+ decreased moving away from the wall** instead of increasing. *I can include the images of the residuals and Cf plot if anyone asks.*

**One thing to note is I could not get the flow to converge at all unless I enabled pseudotime, however, I'm worried this is a leading source of the errors I am seeing.**

I am pretty lost at what else I might try, since the problem could be a combination of a bad choice of geometry, boundary conditions, boundary layer mesh, or turbulence model. Is it possible to get some recommendations from others who are more experienced? I was expecting this to be a pretty simple case to run.

Please let me know if you have any questions.